# Is equal tubing on scaled, non-realized instance curves possible?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

By realizing these curve circle instances, I'm able to get equal tubing per instance.

[image]

Without realizing, the tubing is scaled proportionally to the scale of the instance.
[image]

I was just wondering if there's a way to get equal tubing without realizing. I believe realizing is more computationally expensive and coloring realized instances was trickier than non-realized.

I have been most suspicious about the *Scale Elements* node because I have scaled control points of curves in edit mode before instead of scaling the curve to affect the curve's size without affecting tubing. However, I can't achieve per-instance unique element scaling.
[image]

I believe there's a possibility that this task is impossible, but I am curious.

Comment: Short answer: no. Instances are always identical, and you can only affect the transformation without realizing it.